# Gulp compile command isn't compiling the SRC folder from TS to JS in DIst folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp

I'm using Gulp to compile my type script into java script. When I initiate the Gulp command it will compile everything in my src folder and puts the compiles files in dist folder which are is Java script now but i only see only one file present in dist folder after compilation i.e. config.json where i am expecting all the files in src to be present in dist after compilation. I am using gulp compile command to compile my files in SRC.

Kindly scroll down the code below to see the folder structure as well.
Thank you.

Here's my **gulpfile.js**

````
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var zip = require('gulp-zip');
var del = require('del');
var install = require('gulp-install');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var awsLambda = require("node-aws-lambda");
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var gulpMocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

const babel = require('gulp-babel');
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del(['./dist','./testJs', './dist.zip']);
});


gulp.task('compile', function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts' ]) //'typings/**/*.d.ts'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts({
      noImplicitAny: false,
      removeComments: true,
      preserveConstEnums: true,
      target: 'es2015',
      module: 'commonjs',
      noExternalResolve: true,
      exclude: ["node_modules", "dist"]
    }))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: [ 'es2015' ],
      plugins: ['transform-runtime']      
    }))
    // sourceRoot must be relative to the running directory
    // It appears VSCode does resolve the path relative to the cwd
    // so using something like /src doesn't work, it has to be relative
    // to the /dist folder where we will run the app from
    // Need to test if maps help when errors are thrown in aws and if we should upload them
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { sourceRoot: '../src' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    ,
    gulp.src(['src/**/*.json'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});


gulp.task('deploy', function (callback) {
    return runSequence(
        'clean',
        'compile',
        'compiletest',
        'test',
        'node-mods',
    callback
    );
});```

**Folder structure before running gulp compile**

  |
    |_ [src folder]
        |_CC_ToMRDR
        |_Central Repository
        app.ts
        config.json
        test.ts        

    |_ [other folder's and files like node modules,package.json,tsconfig.json etc]




**Folder structure after running gulp compile**

  |
    |_ [src folder]
        |_CC_ToMRDR
        |_Central Repository
        app.ts
        config.json
        test.ts        

    |
    |_ [dist folder]
          config.json

    |_ [other folder's and files like node modules,package.json,tsconfig.json etc]
````

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first `gulp.src` like this:

```
return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
```

and the second

```
.pipe(gulp.src('src/**/*.json'))
```

Comma breaks the compilation. The second `gulp.src` must be added as a `pipe` or it overwrites the first (cfr. https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/working-with-files/).

More in depth:

```
gulp.task('compile', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
    // some coding here
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(gulp.src('src/**/*.json'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Sorry for the edits, but you’re using an older Gulp.js syntax and I was a bit confused.

Comment: Hi Federico i changed the code to be like this:


```gulp.task('compile', function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.json']) //'typings/**/*.d.ts'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts({
      noImplicitAny: false,
      removeComments: true,
      preserveConstEnums: true,
      target: 'es2015',
      module: 'commonjs',
      noExternalResolve: true,
      exclude: ["node_modules", "dist"]
    }))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: [ 'es2015' ],
      plugins: ['transform-runtime']      
    }))```

Comment: I edited my reply because you have two different kinds of files. Check the changes: it should work now.

Comment: I am getting this error now:
(node:20896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: TypeScript: Compilation failed

Comment: Sorry, I double checked because I use a newer syntax for Gulp.js: if this doesn’t work either, I guess the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Federico. Sorry for the delay. Yes this works now. Thank you so much